# How to prevent Turbo progress bar and spinning activity indicator from Rails 7 link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs, turbo

I have a Rails 7 app with Turbo and Stimulus. I have a link_to that triggers a controller action but not a render or redirect. The basic functionality is correct, but clicking the link initiates the Turbo progress bar and the spinning activity indicator on the browser tab and they never finish. Is there a way to prevent them from starting?

The link is in a partial used multiple places for liking things. All UI changes are done with JavaScript.

```
<%= link_to "/#{controller}/#{object.id}/like", data: { "turbo-method": :patch, action: 'click->like#likeTapped', "turbo-frame": "_top" }, class: 'like-link'  do %>
```

Rails Controller:

```
  def like
    current_user.toggle_like!(@post)
  end
```

Can I prevent a Turbo visit to keep it from having an activity indicator, or can I make the Rails controller return something that doesn't reload or change scroll position?

Answer (score 1):

[To disable the progress bar entirely](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#displaying-progress), set its `visibility` style to `hidden`:

```css
.turbo-progress-bar {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `remote: :true` helper to make your link send an AJAX request:

```
<%= link_to "/#{controller}/#{object.id}/like", method: :patch, data: { remote: :true, action: 'click->like#likeTapped' }, class: 'like-link' do %>
```

And in controller:

```
  def like
    current_user.toggle_like!(@post)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```